# Error in irlba starting vector near the null space

Tags: r, machine-learning, text-mining, svd

```
train.irbla <- irlba(t(train.tokens.tfidf), nv=300, maxit = 100)
```

I am trying to do a dimensionality reduction. The actual dimension of the train matrix is `1140*5418`.

> Warning in irlba(t(train.tokens.tfidf), nv = 5, maxit = 100) :
>     fast code path error starting vector near the null space; re-trying with fastpath=FALSE.
>
> Error in irlba(t(train.tokens.tfidf), nv = 5, maxit = 100) : 
>     starting vector near the null space